# ngCordova media plugin seekTo doesn't work the first time

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm playing an audio through the ngCordova media plugin using the seekTo method:

```
media.play();
media.seekTo(time);
```

In iOS, the audio plays from the beginning instead of moving the position within the audio file while the first time playing. It only works if I delay the seekTo:

```
media.play();

setTimeout(function () {
  media.seekTo(time);
}, 500);
```

However, this is not reliable and I want to check by Media.MEDIA_RUNNING status instead, which seems this callback is missing in ngCordova.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are entering time into seconds.
Try

```
media.seekTo(time * 1000);
```